# How to access the current ItemType Item value from OnItemDataBound method of ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, listview, itemdatabound

In aspx page:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewPosts" ItemType="Post" 
SelectMethod="ListViewPosts_GetData" runat="server"
OnItemDataBound="ListViewPosts_ItemDataBound">
        ...
        ...
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ListViewPosts_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  ...
  Post p = Item; //where Item stands for the current Post record in ListView.
  ...
}
```

If I have this `ListView` where in `ItemType="Post"`; `Post` is a database table.
How to access the current value of `Item` (which stands for the current record from the`Post` table) in  the code behind method `ListViewPosts_ItemDataBound`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Please note, **Post** should be **DataRow** if **Post** is the table.

```
protected void ListViewPosts_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
   ...
   DataRow p = (DataRow)e.Item.DataItem; //where Item stands for the current Post record in ListView.
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks: Your answer helps me; I got it this way `Post p = e.Item.DataItem as Post;`

Comment: You can cast your DataItem this way also, `Post p = (Post)e.Item.DataItem;`