# How to access the current ItemType Item value from OnItemCommand method of ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, listview, databound

In aspx page:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewPosts" ItemType="Post" 
SelectMethod="ListViewPosts_GetData" runat="server" 
OnItemCommand="Insert_Comment"
OnItemDataBound="ListViewPosts_ItemDataBound">

        ...
        ...
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Insert_Comment(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  ...
  Post p = Item; //where Item stands for the current Post record in ListView.
  ...
}
```

If I have this `ListView` where in `ItemType="Post"`; `Post` is a database table.
How to access the current value of `Item` (which stands for the current record from the`Post` table) in the code behind method `Insert_Comment`

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29733818/1576401) for `OnItemDataBound` method and the code:
 `Post p = e.Item.DataItem as Post` works well. I tried the same code for `OnItemCommand` but the variable `Post p` gets `null` value!!.

I can use `CommandArgument` but I am wondering if I can get the `Post` item directly like the way I can with `OnItemDataBound` methos.

Comment: You can get through the [CommandArgunment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Peyman I added some details (last two paragraphs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `.DataItem` only within `OnItemDataBound`. You may pass the `Id` of the `Item` and use it to bring the `Item` back from the database:

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ListViewPosts" ItemType="Post" 
       SelectMethod="ListViewPosts_GetData" runat="server" 
       OnItemDataBound="ListViewPosts_ItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_InsertComment" CommandName="Insert_Comment" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PostID") %>' Text="Insert" />
      </ItemTemplate>

 </asp:ListView>

 protected void Insert_Comment(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     LinkButton btn_InsertComment = (LinkButton) sender;
     string postId = btn_InsertComment.CommandArgument;
     //use this id to create a new comment
 }
```